# How to generate doxygen block for an existing method?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I remember in the days when I was developing in Java, I could hit a set of keys in Eclipse or IDEA and get a Javadoc block for the method I was in. It would already contain the @param for the parameters and so on.

I am looking for the same thing for doxygen (with C++). I use Eclipse but I am open to any tool that could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple that I didn't see it...

Put the cursor above a function and enter

```
/**
```

when you hit return Eclipse will fill in the doxygen comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for blocks:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Or simplier if you have only one line (I usually use it for members comment):

```
//!
```